# Django {%url 'index2:Redirect' %} have error occurred

Tags: python, django

```
class  R_View(RedirectView):
pattern_name = 'first:login'
query_string = True
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request.path)
    return super(R_View, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

def login(requset):
return render(requset, 'login.html')

urlpatterns = [
path('2/', views.login, name='first'),
path('f/', views.R_View.as_view(), name='Redirect'),


urlpatterns = [
path('gb1/', include(('background.urls', 'first'), namespace='index2'))
```

---

When I input 127.0.0.1:8000/bg1/2
Will report an error：IndexError: pop from empty list
I think the hint is that there is a problem in this line, but I don't know exactly where the problem is：{%url 'index2:Redirect' %}

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RedirectView</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <a href="{%url 'index2:Redirect' %} ?k=10">Go</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is index2 ?

Comment: Provide a namespace for the background application

Comment: in the pattern name you are using first:login ? That means you have used first as namespace somewhere ?

Comment: pattern_name = 'first:login'  >>Is it wrong here?

Comment: See how do I ask a good question [ask].